# Тайм лимит на задаче с ходом коня

Tags: c++

Дана шахматная доска размером m*n.  На каждой клеточке данной доски стоит число (числа могут быть как положительными, так и отрицательными). На данной доске стоит шахматный конь (в левой верхней клетке).

Помогите коню добраться до правой нижней клетки данной доски и при этом собрать наибольшую сумму чисел.

Конь может ходить только четырьмя способами:

2 клетки вправо и 1 вниз (x+2, y+1);

2 клетки вправо и 1 вверх (x+2, y-1);

2 клетки вниз и 1 вправо (x+1, y+2);

2 клетки вниз и 1 влево (x-1, y+2).
В первой строке входного файла даны два значения: m, n – размерность поля.

Далее во входном файле дано само поле.

Левая верхняя клетка доски имеет координаты (1, 1), правая нижняя - (n, m).

В выходной файл должно быть выведено единственное значение – наибольшая сумма, которую сможет собрать конь.

Если конь не может добраться до правой нижней клетки доски, то выведите «-».

Мой код работает, но сайт по какой-то причине ловит ошибку из-за долгой работы программы, хотя даже при очень больших n и m ответ считается моментально. Подскажите что может быть не так.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    long long int n, m, res, path;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int PathMatrix[n + 3][m + 3];
    int ResMatrix[n + 3][m + 3];
    int Matrix[n + 3][m + 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 3; j++)
        {
            ResMatrix[i][j] = -999999;
            PathMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= m + 1; j++)
        {
            cin >> Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    ResMatrix[2][2] = Matrix[2][2];
    PathMatrix[2][2] = 1;
    if (n == 1 and m == 1)
        cout << ResMatrix[2][2];
    else
    {
        int start_i = 2, start_j = 2;
        while ((start_i < n + 1) or (start_j < m + 1))
        {
            if (start_j == m + 1)
                start_i++;
            else
                start_j++;
            int i = start_i, j = start_j;
            while (i <= n + 1 and j >= 2)
            {
                ResMatrix[i][j] = max(max(ResMatrix[i + 1][j - 2], ResMatrix[i - 1][j - 2]),
                                      max(ResMatrix[i - 2][j - 1], ResMatrix[i - 2][j + 1])) + Matrix[i][j];
                PathMatrix[i][j] = PathMatrix[i + 1][j - 2] || PathMatrix[i - 1][j - 2] || PathMatrix[i - 2][j - 1] || PathMatrix[i - 2][j + 1];
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
//        for (int i = 0; i < n + 3; i++)
//        {
//            for (int j = 0; j < m + 3; j++)
//            {
//                cout << PathMatrix[i][j] << " ";
//            }
//            cout << "\n";
//        }
//        for (int i = 0; i < n + 3; i++)
//        {
//            for (int j = 0; j < m + 3; j++)
//            {
//                cout << ResMatrix[i][j] << " ";
//            }
//            cout << "\n";
//        }
    path = PathMatrix[n + 1][m + 1];
    res = ResMatrix[n + 1][m + 1];
    if (path == 1)
        cout << res;
    else
        cout << "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятна формулировка >Мой код работает, но сайт по какой-то причине ловит ошибку из-за долгой работы программы, хотя даже при очень больших n и m ответ считается моментально.  Если он работает, значит ответ получается. Если "сайт ловит ошибку" - значит ответа нет. Если "долгая работа программы", то это противоречит "даже при очень больших n и m ответ считается моментально". А вообще из кода непонятно, что именно вы ищете и считаете.

Comment: Сделайте элементарный тест на 2 хода. Задайте 'n' и 'm' и заведите массив `Matrix[][]` прямо в коде программы и проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код нерабочий. Вы судя по всему пытались сделать волновой алгоритм, но много чего пошло не так:
Вы проходите все клетки матрицы и записываете в них значения по нескольку раз. А надо идти только по тем клеткам, в которые может попасть конь.

```
start_j++;
int i = start_i, j = start_j;
while (i <= n + 1 and j >= 2)
{
    ResMatrix[i][j] = max(...) + Matrix[i][j]; // на каждой итерации по start_j вы заново записываете эту переменную
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

Почему-то в матрицу с весами `ResMatrix[][]` вы изначально записываете `-999999` - зачем? Какой результат вы здесь получите? `max(-999999)` + какое-то правильное значение из `Matrix[i][j]`. И что это получилось за число?

```
// результат операции нелигитимный
    ResMatrix[i][j] = max(max(ResMatrix[i + 1][j - 2], ResMatrix[i - 1][j - 2]),
                          max(ResMatrix[i - 2][j - 1], ResMatrix[i - 2][j + 1])) + Matrix[i][j];
```

В некоторые клетки, в том числе в последнюю можно попасть разными путями. Соответственно у вас должно быть несколько результатов, из которых нужно выбрать максимальный. А у вас такого выбора нигде нет.

---

По алгоритму - он не такой и сложный.

1. С матрицами (то, что вы и пытались сделать)

- заводите 2 матрицы - матрица подсчета весов и матрица где отмечаются пройденные клетки.
- заводите счетчик - номер хода
- на каждой итерации цикла ставите номер хода в клетку матрицы ходов, куда может пойти конь и вес этого хода в соответствующую ячейку матрицы весов
- на следующей итерации проходите по матрице ходов и обрабатываете только те клетки, в которых номер хода с прошлой итерации
- если попадаете в ячейку уже пройденную ранее, выбираете максимальное значение из двух.

2. С двумя стеками (меньше вычислительная сложность)

- делаете свою структуру данных для клетки доски. Что-то вроде `struct Point{ int i, j, w;};` - 2 координаты и вес
- заводите 2 стека (обычно `std::vector<Point>` или `std::set<Point>`)
- заносите в первый стек изначальное положение коня  - клетка `{ 0, 0, w}`
- на каждой итерации обрабатываете и удаляете клетки из первого стека, занося во второй стек клетки, в которые может пойти конь. Например на первой итерации, при обработке клетки `{0,0}` во второй стек добавятся клетки `{ 1, 2, w}` и `{ 2, 1, w}`  считая веса таких ходов
- проверяете в стеке совпадающие клетки, оставляете одну - с максимальным весом
- меняете стеки местами `std::swap( , )`

Comment: я удивлён что в этом списке нет алгоритма Дейкстры.

Comment: @pavel Может из-за отрицательных весов?